# How do I transpose an Excel table to unique columns from many duplicate rows? (preferably in PowerQuery)

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I've looked everywhere, and tried a lot, seemingly most people don't need this problem solved :-(
I have a table with two columns.
Column A (TAG) has 4 distinct values, repeating in that pattern over and over. Those shall become my distinct Column names
Column B (VALUE) has the matching values for those tags.

**Example table:**
[image: Source Table]

Now I simply would like to create a table looking like this:
(Each distinct Value from the TAG row becomes a column header and all the values from the VALUE column become the individual values underneath those new columns)

**Desired Target Table:**
[image: Desired Target Table]

I'd preferably do all this transposing in PowerQuery already when I import the CSV the data came from, but would be OK to do this in some range/table operation later as well.

Any help would be REALLY appreciated :-)

Comment: you mean like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pivot-columns-power-query-abc9c8da-3be9-44c4-886e-0be331ab387a?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us (see without aggregation section)

Comment: You're looking for Pivot Columns: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pivot-columns-power-query-abc9c8da-3be9-44c4-886e-0be331ab387a?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Answer (score 2):

In Power Query, you would Pivot the TAG column, with the VALUE column as the values and `no aggregation`.

However, if you do just that on your data set, you would get error values returned because you have multiple entries for the same Pivot value.

That can be avoided by adding an Index column that numbers each of the individual tag entries sequentially.

In order to do this, and also allow for the TAG's not always being in the same order, you can

- Group by the Tag
- add an index column to each subtable
- Expand the tables
- Pivot on TAG with no aggregation
- Remove the Index column

In the code below, examine the comments and the Applied Steps to better understand.

*If this method is too slow on your data set, there is a custom function published that may execute more quickly.*

```
let

//replace next lines to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TAG", type text}, {"VALUE", type text}}),

//Group By Tage
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"TAG"}, {

        //add an Index column to each subtable
        {"with Index", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index",0,1), type table [TAG=nullable text, VALUE=nullable text, Index=Int64.Type]}}),

//Expand the sub tables
    #"Expanded with Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "with Index", {"VALUE", "Index"}),

//Pivot with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded with Index", List.Distinct(#"Expanded with Index"[TAG]), "TAG", "VALUE"),

//Remove the Index column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Edited to show a custom function for executing a non-aggregation pivot***

**Custom Function**
*paste into a blank query and rename as in the code comments*

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

//Rename:  fnPivotAll 

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

***Main Code***

```
let

//replace next lines to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TAG", type text}, {"VALUE", type text}}),

//call custom pivot function
    pivot = fnPivotAll(#"Changed Type","TAG","VALUE")
in
    pivot
```

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH Ron! You are my hero of the day. Your suspicion around performance was correct as well, it's really slow for a dataset with around 500k rows :-( Would you possibly be able to point me to the pre-defined function you were referencing in your response?
Trying to upvote your reply, but I don't seem to have any reputation, nor am I sure how to get such a thing.

Comment: @MaxWinkler  I will edit my answer to show the custom function.  You obtain reputation by participating.  And, you should always be able to mark a response to your question as an Answer. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.